# How to create an object which stores mappings from a word in a vocabulary to its index?

Tags: python, nlp, vocabulary

I have a tokenized list of words in a vocabulary. (It's been passed through a set, so there are no duplicates.)

**My problem**

I want to generate a method which creates a dictionary that allows a mapping from the word to its index in the vocabulary.

**My attempt**

My current method is like so:

```
mapping = { w : vocabulary.index(w) for w in vocabulary }
```

This should work but it is far too inefficient, probably due to repeatedly using vocabulary.index(w) for thousands of words.

**Question**

Is there a library that I can use that does this more efficiently? Or just more efficient methods?

Thanks.

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION 1**

Currently, each time a word is reached in 'vocabulary', vocabulary.index() is implemented, which required a pass through 'vocabulary' to identify the index, which is done for every word. As suggested in an answer, a possibility is to enumerate 'vocabulary' first. This allows one pass through it to identify the index, like so:

```
mapping = { w : i for i, w in enumerate(vocabulary) }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by changing your code as follows.
mapping = { w : i for i, w in enumerate(vocabulary) }
where i is the index of the word w.

Comment: Oh great, that sounds good. So in doing this, you enumerate the vocab, which allows you to pass through it once to create the dict?